# Batch file newbiew - error checking help

Tags: batch-file

I have created the below script to aid IT staff with USMT migrations. The aim is of it is to list the available migration stores categorised by date and then select them using a series of user input menu's.

The problem is however that is if the user inputs the correct value, there are no issues, if a wrong value is entered then the script continues and contains incorrect values in the directory structure variables. I have tried to use if not exist but my code just caused the script into an infinite loop. If anyone can help me with a way to mitigate these errors I'd appreciate it I'm an infrastructure guy not a programmer ;)

```
:LOADSTATEW732
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%" 
Set /P loadstateday=Please enter day(01-31):
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%" 
Set /P loadstatemonth=Please enter month(01-12):
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%\%loadstatemonth%"
Set /P loadstateyear=Please enter year(Example 2011):
cls
ECHO You have selected: Day: %loadstateday% Month: %loadstatemonth% Year: %loadstateyear%
ECHO.
Set /P loadstateset=Are these settings correct? (Enter Yes/No):
IF %loadstateset% == Yes GOTO LOADSTATEGO
IF %loadstateset% == Y GOTO LOADSTATEGO
IF %loadstateset% == NO GOTO LOADSTATEW732
IF %loadstateset% == N GOTO LOADSTATEW732
:LOADSTATEGO
ECHO Exporting Migration Settings...
"%CD%\loadstate.exe" \\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%  Loadstateday%\%Loadstatemonth%\%Loadstateyear% /c /i:userfiles.xml /i:migapp.xml /v:12
ECHO.
pause
GOTO MENU:
```

Entire Script

```
@ECHO OFF
:START

:MIGSERVER
cls
ECHO.
ECHO ____________________________________________________________
ECHO Please set the deployment server
ECHO For example: UKHQITS017 FRPRAPS002 HUHKAPS001 etc
ECHO.
ECHO By default this script is configured to use the reminst 
ECHO share for USMT migrations.
ECHO ____________________________________________________________
ECHO.
Set /P MigServer=Please enter USMT Server:
cls
ECHO Server set to: %migserver% 
ECHO Please insure this is correct before continuing
pause
cls
GOTO MENU:

:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ________________________________________________
ECHO User State Migration Tool v0.1
ECHO ________________________________________________
ECHO.
ECHO 1 Check Directory parameters
ECHO 2 Set USMT Server
ECHO 3 Delete Unused User Profiles (XP ONLY)
ECHO 4 Export migration settings from host system (Windows XP 32Bit)
ECHO 5 Export migration settigns to target system (Windows 7 32Bit)
ECHO 6 Exit
ECHO.
SET /P userChoice=Choose Option(1-6):

IF %userchoice% == 1 GOTO DIRPARAMS
IF %userchoice% == 2 GOTO MIGSERVER
IF %userchoice% == 3 GOTO PROFDEL
IF %userchoice% == 4 GOTO SCANSTATEXP32
IF %userchoice% == 5 GOTO LOADSTATEW732
IF %userchoice% == 6 GOTO QUITMENU


:DIRPARAMS
cls
ECHO.
ECHO  Current USMT x86 Folder: %CD%
ECHO  Current USMT Migration Store Server: %migserver%
ECHO.
ECHO   Please make sure of the following
ECHO   before continuing.
ECHO.
ECHO   1. You have set the correct migration server in the batch file.
ECHO   2. The above directorys exist
ECHO   3. The appropriate files are included within them
ECHO.
pause
cls
GOTO MENU:

:PROFDEL
cls
ECHO User Profile Deletion - Please select which profiles you wish to remove.
"%CD%\delprof2.exe" -c:127.0.0.1 -p -d:90
ECHO.
pause
GOTO MENU:

:SCANSTATEXP32
cls
ECHO Creating migration store.......
"%CD%\scanstate.exe" "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%date%" /o /c /i:userfiles.xml /i:migapp.xml /v:12
ECHO.
pause
GOTO MENU:

:LOADSTATEW732
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%" 
Set /P loadstateday=Please enter day(01-31):
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%" 
Set /P loadstatemonth=Please enter month(01-12):
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%\%loadstatemonth%"
Set /P loadstateyear=Please enter year(Example 2011):
cls
ECHO You have selected: Day: %loadstateday% Month: %loadstatemonth% Year: %loadstateyear%
ECHO.
Set /P loadstateset=Are these settings correct? (Enter Yes/No):
IF %loadstateset% == Yes GOTO LOADSTATEGO
IF %loadstateset% == Y GOTO LOADSTATEGO
IF %loadstateset% == NO GOTO LOADSTATEW732
IF %loadstateset% == N GOTO LOADSTATEW732

:LOADSTATEGO
ECHO Exporting Migration Settings...
"%CD%\loadstate.exe" \\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%Loadstateday%\%Loadstatemonth%\%Loadstateyear% /c /i:userfiles.xml /i:migapp.xml /v:12
ECHO.
pause
GOTO MENU:

:QUITMENU
ECHO USM TOOL v0.1 has ended.
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IF EXIST command on it. However, standard syntax for IF EXIST only works on files. Referenced here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994
You can structure it as follows:

```
:LOADSTATEW732
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%" 
Set /P loadstateday=Please enter day(01-31):
cls
IF EXIST "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%\NUL" (
 GOTO MONTH
) ELSE (
 ECHO Not a valid day integer.
 PAUSE
 GOTO LOADSTATEW732
)
:MONTH
cls
dir "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%" 
Set /P loadstatemonth=Please enter month(01-12):
cls
IF EXIST "\\%migserver%\reminst\USMT XP to Windows 7\32Bit\%username%\%loadstateday%\%loadstatemonth%\NUL" (
 GOTO YEAR
) ELSE (
 ECHO Not a valid month integer.
 PAUSE
 GOTO MONTH
)
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but with your code the original problem still remains. If a user enters say 25, your code will verfiy that as being correct and go to month, however if 25 does not exist in the UNC path it will fall over because it's trying to perform a DIR on a non existant folder.

Comment: Also, not sure if you did this by accident, but there are 2 instances of the tag :LOADSTATEW732 in your script. One at the beginning and one towards the end. Each GOTO tag must be unique.

Comment: Actually those were two distinct snippets as you can now clearly see. The 'first' occurrence of `:LOADSTATEW732` was part of the *excerpt* from the complete script, and the other one belonged to the entire script.

Comment: totally overlooked the "Entire Script" line between the two =/